# XML to XML Transformation through XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

The Input XML is

```
                                    <CELL col="F">
                                  <Para apprevbar="F">s281w0-602
                                   <a>AB</a>
                                     <b>CD <d> RT </d> 78</b>
                                      <c>EF</c>....etc
                                    </Para>
                                  </CELL>
```

I want the output as

```
                                <CELL col="F">
                         <Para apprevbar="F">s281w0-602
                               AB
                               CD
                               RT
                               78
                               EF...etc
                              </Para>
                              </CELL>
```

Can you please tell me any xsl ideas to transform the above input xml to get the above output.

Comment: Please show us the XSLT you have tried so far.

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

       <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
      
       <xsl:template match="CELL">
<Para>

          <xsl:value-of select="Para" />

</Para>
 

   
</xsl:template>      </xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Could you edit that into the question rather than posting it as a comment please - code formatting doesn't come through very well in comments.

Comment: Now I Updated the question.Can you please look into that and tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Based on your comments and your edits you seem to want to strip all element content from the `Para` element so you can use

```
<xsl:template match="Para//*">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

to continue with the approach taken so far but you could as well use

```
<xsl:template match="Para">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to simply output the string value of the `Para` element as the new content.

Comment: The two templates I posted will copy any contents of the `a` element.

Comment: If you have other elements that need the same treatment as the `a` elements then use `<xsl:template match="a | b | c"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>`.

Comment: But the a ,b,c tag is not constant.It can vary with any tag names.is there any generic match to remove all tag values and get the value alone?

Comment: If you mean by this, "any tag child of a <Para> tag", then use "*[parent::Para]" as the Xpath for the match attribute.

Comment: If you use `<xsl:template match="Para/*"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>` then all child elements of the `Para` elements get the same treatment.

Comment: Thanks Martin.Suppose we have the following scanerio like:<a>1<b>2<c>3</c></b></a><d>5</d>.Can you please tell me some ideas to get all values.

Comment: Sorry, but you seem to ask a new question after every suggestion made. Consider to then post a new question on StackOverflow, it does not make sense to exchange code sample in comments.

Comment: Sorry,Now i updated the Question.can you please provide me some  ideas.

Comment: How to Apply the above two template into one template to get the desired result?

Comment: Use two templates if you want to use that approach, the first is the identity transformation template and the second is one of the suggestions I made. It does not make sense to combine those templates into a single one.